# How do I get a Phone instance in android?

Tags: android, telephony

I have to use android ITelephony the internal classes on android telephony. I am using ITelephony to make calls by getting its instance as

```
ITelephony phone = ITelephony.Stub.asInterface(
    ServiceManager.getService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
);
```

and then calling with

```
phone.call(destNum);
```

Now I need to perform other actions like holding a call. ITelephony does not provide an API for this, but I found a Phone class that has `switchHoldingAndActive()`, but to call this I need a Phone instance to the currently running active call. I tried

```
Phone PhoneActive = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
```

but its giving me an exception saying

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

What is the correct way to get a Phone Instance?

Answer (score 5):

There is no correct way to get Phone instance.
AFAIK, getDefaultPhone() returns the instance of the current active Phone sub-class (GSM/CDMA) only if it is created by your thread (via PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone()).
However, I believe that the instance is created by pre-installed Call application, so if you try it won't work.
Long time ago I tried to use reflection to sign up for precise call state updates and stuck because of security exception. My application had to be running in system process...
My code was like this:

```
mPhoneFactory = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory");
Method mMakeDefaultPhone = mPhoneFactory.getMethod("makeDefaultPhone", new Class[] {Context.class});
mMakeDefaultPhone.invoke(null, getContext());

Method mGetDefaultPhone = mPhoneFactory.getMethod("getDefaultPhone", null);
mPhone = mGetDefaultPhone.invoke(null);

Method mRegisterForStateChange = mPhone.getClass().getMethod("registerForPreciseCallStateChanged",
new Class[]{Handler.class, Integer.TYPE, Object.class});            

mRegisterForStateChange.invoke(mPhone, mHandler, CALL_STATE_CHANGED, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

is an exception thrown when you call a UI-Thread-only-method on a `Thread` that is not th UI thread.

Try either to use an `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread`, call `runOnUiThread`, or `postRunnable`.

Comment: hi yes mine is not a UI thread its a Service but i am using ASYN Task please look into my code and let me know what i should change

Comment: in onPreExecute method of ASYNC task i am calling Phone.getDefaultPhone()